# How to add UserCustomAction to SPSite using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I'm trying to add a *UserCustomAction* to SPSite (NOT SPWeb/SPList) using Powershell, but it doesn't seem to get saved to database and, thus, it is not available on my site.

Right after creating and doing `$newUCA.Update()`, the new *UserCustomAction* can be found using:

```
$site.UserCustomActions | ? {$_.Title -eq "myUCATitle"}
```

After disposing and getting `$site` again, the new UCA is not available under `$site.UserCustomActions`, which means it wasn't saved.

I'm using SharePoint 2016 SharePoint Management Shell (Powershell v. 5).

This is the code I'm using:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "Site_Url"
$newUCA = $site.UserCustomActions.Add()
$newUCA.Title = "myUCATitle"
$newUCA.Location = "ScriptLink"
$newUCA.Sequence = 200
$newUCA.Url = "~sitecollection/myLibrary/myJSfile.js"
$newUCA.Update();
```

When I open my site, right click and select "View Page Source", I should be able to see a reference to `myJSfile.js` file in a  tag, yet the link is not there.

Answer (score 1):

To link a JS file on a SharePoint site, instead of `$newUCA.Url`, we need to use the `$newUCA.ScriptSrc` property.

```
$site = Get-SPSite "Site_Url"
$newUCA = $site.UserCustomActions.Add()
$newUCA.Title = "myUCATitle"
$newUCA.Location = "ScriptLink"
$newUCA.Sequence = 200
$newUCA.ScriptSrc = "~sitecollection/myLibrary/myJSfile.js"
$newUCA.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PnP powershell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) for this, I used below script often. [download link](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

```
Connect-PNPOnline -Url http://sp:12001
Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name "ScriptLinkGetListItem" -Url /siteassets/ScriptLinkGetListItem.js -Sequence 9999 -Scope Site
```